# If Absolute Hot and Absolute Zero, collided what would happen?

Tags: science-based, temperature

**If a substance at [Absolute Hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_hot) and a substance at [Absolute Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_zero) collided, what would happen to the resulting mixture??**

Assume this was done on Earth in a sort of collision facility.

I'm working on story about two scientists who are researching temperatures, and how they would affect the world. In an advanced society, I didn't know what the impact of the collision would mean (and have since found out Absolute Hot on Earth is a REALLY bad idea). It would determine how hot my "mutants" will be, and the sort of cancelling out I would need to make them equal (one is evil, the other is good).

Note: I have no idea what to tag this as.

Comment: Do not try this at home.  We're what you call experts.

Comment: Peripherally relevant https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature

Comment: There's no puzzle there. Whichever temperature you meant as the hot one (the link gave two), you would end up with half that.  More generally, the substance would have different heat capacities at different phases.  Just substitute "value xx degrees" for Absolute Hot and you'll see it's not a puzzle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Physics, but I can't vote for that option for some reason

Comment: @Toadfish **Do not vote to close based on that reason.**

Comment: @Samuel noted, apologies.

Comment: what you want here is negative temperatures

Comment: @Toadfish It's perfectly appropriate to vote to close as off-topic *if in your informed opinion the question is off-topic here*. You shouldn't vote to close just because a question is *also on-topic elsewhere*. Note the difference between the two.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**It would be so close to absolute hot that you probably couldn't tell the difference.**

The two concepts are not really on opposite ends of a spectrum from what we consider "normal" (~300 Kelvin). In the cold direction, there is 300 Kelvin, in the hot direction there is 1.416785(71)×10<sup>32</sup> Kelvin.

If you mix two equal amounts of substances at the temperatures it would all be in the 10<sup>32</sup> Kelvin range still.

Not all that impressive, unfortunately. Note that doing this on Earth, or having anything that is absolute hot anywhere near Earth, would be the end of the experiment and Earth.

Comment: @RobWatts From what we consider "normal" is 300 Kelvin to 0. The point is it's the same order of magnitude.

Comment: @RobWatts, even splitting it in half would only bring that 32 exponent down to a 31.

Comment: @RobWatts Yep. Just making it clear that it's not like we're in the middle of two opposite sides of the temperature scale.

Comment: @Samuel TIL humans are friggin' cold.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon That's the definition, yep. Read the other comments first if you're still confused.

Comment: By definition, wouldn't absolute hot require all the energy in the universe? Which means, in order to create absolute hot, wouldn't you have to first destroy earth (and yourself)?

Comment: @slebetman No, that's not the definition of absolute hot.

Answer (score 3):

**Everything in the region would be a goner.**

For one, the absolute zero would do nothing to impact the absolute hot, since absolute hot is far beyond 0 on the positive side of the number line.

It would do a minuscule amount to the hot volume, and as a result (nevermind having that heat around to begin with) could form a hypothetical object known as a **[kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_%28astrophysics%29)**, spacetime warped into a black hole from the sheer amount of energy, and that's without consideration for the fact that the heat would incinerate everything in that region of space.

You can say goodbye to the Earth and everything around it. It's like throwing an ice cube into a volcano except the volcano is the Big Bang.